# What should I be passing to GoogleAnalyticsTracker.startSession()

Tags: android, google-analytics

Should I be passing just my Google Analytics account number (e.g. UA-12345678), or the website -specific code (e.g. UA-12345678-1). It seems I should be passing the latter but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter, ie, `UA-12345678-1`

The former doesn't have any meaning to Google Analytics, since the data stored in, say `UA-123-1` isn't shared with data stored in `UA-123-555`, and vice-versa.